# Way to add single quote character in string in constructing oracle query in python

Tags: python

I have this method that creates the query and passes two string parameters. But when I test this it has escape characters '' before the single quote '''.

The query can only accept native queries in string form

I also tried string.replace method but doesnt work

```
replace('\\', '')
```

Here is the code

```
def update_query(self, status, row_id):
    return '''UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = {0} WHERE ID = {1}'''.format(status, row_id)
```

Here is the sample output:

```
'UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = 'Success' WHERE ID = 1'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think you absolutely should be using prepared statements here, which the other answers don't seem to be recommending (for whatever reason).  Try using something along these lines:

```py
sql = "UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = :status WHERE ID = :id"
cursor.prepare(sql)
cursor.execute(None, {'status':status, 'id':row_id})
```

One advantage of using prepared statements here is that it frees the user from having to worry about how to properly escape the literal placeholders in the query.  Instead, we only need to bind a variable with the correct type to the statement, and Oracle will handle the rest.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am using a helper class to execute db queries that only accepts native queries in string form.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for formatting your string

```
def update_query(self,status, row_id):
    return f"UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = '{status}' WHERE ID = {row_id}"

>>> update_query("Success",1)
"UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = 'Success' WHERE ID = 1"
```

Comment: I am using an older version of python, this is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `\` in the code

```
def update_query(self, status, row_id):
    return '''UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = \'{0}\' WHERE ID = {1}'''.format(status, row_id)
```

Comment: the backslash (\\) isn't necessary.

Comment: adding backslash will not recognize the first bind variable